# How to extend SQL calculation query to give results for multiple parent rows

Tags: mysql, sql

The following query (for an educational app) calculates a user's score on a particular drill. It works on four tables - user, drill, question and answer. Each question belongs to a drill and each answer belongs to a question and a user (an answer is unique to a user and a question). Questions are multiple choice and an answer is correct if answer.selectedChoice = 1. A user's score for a drill is based on the most recent five answers for that drill and the weight assigned to a correct answer is scaled based on how quickly it's answered.

I'm trying to figure out how to extend this query so that rather than only getting a user's score for a particular drill, I can get the user's score for every drill for which they've answered at least one question. I've been investigating rewriting it as correlated subquery, but so far my efforts have come up short. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
SELECT data.*,
    SUM(data.isCorrect * (IF(rawScore < 0, 0, IF(rawScore > 1, 1, rawScore)))) / 5 AS score
FROM
    (SELECT 
        answer.id,
        IF(answer.selectedChoice = 1, 1, 0) AS isCorrect,  
        (1 - (answer.timeElapsed - question.baseTime) / (4 * question.baseTime)) as rawScore
     FROM
        answer,
        question
     WHERE
        answer.questionID = question.id AND
        question.drillID = :drillID AND
        answer.userID = :userID
     ORDER BY
        answer.created DESC
     LIMIT 
        5) as data
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below. Assumed that for "they've answered at least one question" condition you are using answer.created column.
The idea is get all questions for one user and calculate isCorrect, rawScore, score( if case) any data that you need and group by question.drillID, answer.userID (user's score for every drill), then using HAVING clause get only the users that answered at least one question (which they've answered at least one question).

Below query might get you wrong results - please post table structure and sample data and i can create a demo for you.

```
SELECT 
   answer.id,
   IF(answer.selectedChoice = 1, 1, 0) AS isCorrect,  
   (1 - (answer.timeElapsed - question.baseTime) / (4 * question.baseTime)) as rawScore
-- SUM(data.isCorrect * (IF(rawScore < 0, 0, IF(rawScore > 1, 1, rawScore)))) / 5 AS score
-- SUM(IF(answer.selectedChoice = 1, 1, 0) * (IF(1 - (answer.timeElapsed - question.baseTime) / (4 * question.baseTime)) < 0, 0, IF((1 - (answer.timeElapsed - question.baseTime) / (4 * question.baseTime)) > 1, 1, (1 - (answer.timeElapsed - question.baseTime) / (4 * question.baseTime)))))) / 5 AS score
FROM answer a 
INNER JOIN question q ON answer.questionID = question.id
GROUP BY 
   question.drillID, answer.userID
WHERE 
   answer.userID = :userID 
HAVING 
   COUNT(answer.created) >= 1;
```